# Flutter: variable not updaing for widget even when surrounding it with setState()

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

This is a button in an animated container to animate the changes in dimensions and color. However the button state that should change on tap is only locally changing the variable not for the whole widget.

when starting the on tap the print is always "idle" and at the end the print is always "loading" as it should. but nothing changes and when tapping again the buttonState is still idle.

The container in the tree:

```
                     AnimatedContainer(
                        curve: Curves.easeOutCubic,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                        height: sHeight * 0.07,
                        width: _buttonState == CustomButtonState.idle
                            ? sWidth * 0.7
                            : _buttonState == CustomButtonState.loading
                                ? sHeight * 0.07
                                : _buttonState == CustomButtonState.fail
                                    ? sWidth * 0.7
                                    : sWidth * 0.7,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: sWidth * kcardHorizontalMargin,
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: _buttonState == CustomButtonState.idle
                                ? Colors.grey.shade500
                                : _buttonState == CustomButtonState.loading
                                    ? kblueColor
                                    : _buttonState == CustomButtonState.fail
                                        ? kredColor
                                        : ksecondaryColor,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              child: _buttonState == CustomButtonState.idle
                                  ? Container(
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Confirm',
                                        style: kloginButtonText.copyWith(
                                            color: ksecondaryColor),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : _buttonState == CustomButtonState.loading
                                      ? Container(
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                            backgroundColor: ksecondaryColor,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : _buttonState == CustomButtonState.fail
                                          ? Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment
                                                      .spaceBetween,
                                              children: [
                                                Icon(
                                                  Icons.cancel,
                                                  color: kredColor,
                                                ),
                                                Container(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'Fail',
                                                    style: kloginButtonText
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                            color:
                                                                ksecondaryColor),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            )
                                          : Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment
                                                      .spaceBetween,
                                              children: [
                                                Icon(
                                                  Icons.check,
                                                  color: ksecondaryColor,
                                                ),
                                                Container(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'Success',
                                                    style: kloginButtonText
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                            color:
                                                                ksecondaryColor),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                              onTap: () {
                                print(_buttonState);
                                if (_buttonState == CustomButtonState.idle) {
                                  changeButtonState(
                                      CustomButtonState.loading);
                                } else if (_buttonState ==
                                    CustomButtonState.loading) {
                                  changeButtonState(CustomButtonState.success);
                                } else {
                                  changeButtonState(CustomButtonState.idle);
                                }
                                print("after ontap: $_buttonState");
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

The custom button state:

```
enum CustomButtonState { idle, loading, success, fail }
```

The changeButtonState method:

```
  CustomButtonState changeButtonState(CustomButtonState state) {
print("changing to: $state");
switch (state) {
  case CustomButtonState.idle:
    setState(() {
      _buttonState = CustomButtonState.idle;
    });
    break;
  case CustomButtonState.loading:
    setState(() {
      _buttonState = CustomButtonState.loading;
    });
    break;
  case CustomButtonState.fail:
    setState(() {
      _buttonState = CustomButtonState.fail;
    });
    break;
  case CustomButtonState.success:
    setState(() {
      _buttonState = CustomButtonState.success;
    });
    break;
}
print("changed to: $_buttonState");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to click on this button and had got following results in console. And I also got 3 rendering state for the button: Confirm, Loading, Success

```
flutter: CustomButtonState.idle
flutter: changing to: CustomButtonState.loading
flutter: changed to: CustomButtonState.loading
flutter: after ontap: CustomButtonState.loading
flutter: CustomButtonState.loading
flutter: changing to: CustomButtonState.success
flutter: changed to: CustomButtonState.success
flutter: after ontap: CustomButtonState.success
flutter: CustomButtonState.success
flutter: changing to: CustomButtonState.idle
flutter: changed to: CustomButtonState.idle
flutter: after ontap: CustomButtonState.idle
```

I think GestureDetector should wrap whole AnimatedContainer, because now this button change it's state only on the text click instead of whole container.